# R xts - subscript out of bound while using last()

Tags: r, xts

I found a strange error while using last() function in xts package in R.

I have a xts object of dim 740*1, but last(data, 1) returns the error:

```
> tail(data)
            [,1]
2017-02-28 2.092
2017-03-01 2.093
2017-03-02    NA
2017-03-03    NA
2017-03-06    NA
2017-03-07    NA
> dim(data)
[1] 740   1
> last(data,1)
Error in x[[order(order_by)[n]]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Could you help me understand why this happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when the function is getting masked by the same function name from another package that is also loaded in the R session.

```
dplyr::last(data, 1)
```

> Error in x[[order(order_by)[n]]] : subscript out of bounds

```
last(data, 1)
#         [,1]
#2017-04-11    5
```

In the above, it is the `dplyr` `last` got masked by `xts::last`, so it worked fine in this case.  Based on the order of loading the packages (here we loaded `xts` after `dplyr`) this could happen.  Suppose, we loaded `dplyr` after `xts` on a fresh `R` session the reverse gets true

```
library(xts)
#Loading required package: zoo

#Attaching package: ‘zoo’

#The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

#as.Date, as.Date.numeric

library(dplyr)

#Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

#The following objects are masked from ‘package:xts’:

#first, last   ####note this line


data <- xts(1:5, order.by = Sys.Date()+1:5)
last(data, 1)
```

> Error in x[[order(order_by)[n]]] : subscript out of bounds

Here, the option is to use `::`

```
xts::last(data, 1)
#           [,1]
#2017-04-11    5
```

#### data

```
data <- xts(1:5, order.by = Sys.Date()+1:5)
```